# Automate search in web site

Tags: beautifulsoup

I have a list of items to look for in a web site and I'm trying to automate the research; I'm new with BeautifulSoup and I'm not sure if what I'm looking for is possible.

The search box in this web site has the following tag:

```
<input id="q" name="q" type="text" **value="moby dick"** class="ui-autocomplete-input">
```

Suppose I want to search for a new book "Amleto" instead of "moby dick". I've tried

```
content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip() 
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
searchBox = soup.find('input', {'id': 'q'})
newSearch = Tag(builder=soup.builder, name='input', attrs={'id':'q',
                                                               'name':'q',
                                                               'type':"text",
                                                               '**value':"Amleto"**,
                                                               'class':"ui-autocomplete-input")

searchBox.replaceWith(newSearch)
```

This code works, It finds the correct tag and replace the value "moby dick" with Amleto. In fact, if I then run:

```
soup.find('input', {'id': 'q'})
```

I get "Amleto"

Nevertheless, in the search box I still see "moby dick"; the "replaceWith" function seems to have changed the html code but this change has not been applied

Is there any way to apply this kind of changes or I'm off track?

I hope I'm making myself clear, thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1):

I think a better approach would be to use selenium to automate browser activities.
Beautiful soup can parse html, However selenium will open a new browser window,navigate to the required URL, type the search items name and press search emulating real user behavior.
It is mostly used to automate front end tests However you can use it to accomplish your task.

docs : https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/